# User provided service in Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I can create a `UPS` for a space easily enough.. However, it fails when I target an ORG. Is this supported? I don't want to create the same service 10 times etc.

Here is the error I get:

```
Creating user provided service MYSERVICE in org MYORG / 
space as MYID... FAILED Server error, status code: 400, 
error code: 1002, message: Invalid relation: Could not 
find VCAP::CloudController::Space with guid:
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what API call you are making, if you are using the CF CLI, etc?

Comment: cf cups testso -p '{"username":"user","password":"password:"}' command worked for me.

Comment: Hi Jake.. Using the CF command line tx

Comment: @vmmovva.  yes that works.. but is limited to the space your are connected to.  I want to add a user provided service that the entire org has access to.  Consider.. the same credential needed for all spaces.  Why create it 'n' times?